# How to make a view to cover your screen despite different screens

Tags: android, layout

I have one layout in which there is one relative layout inside main layout.This layout is displayed in center of the main layout.In some device it is covering most part(having some widgets above and below it).I tested it with different emulators.In some mulator it is not covering that much are.I want it should cover same portion in every screen(i.e. in every emulator).Can i use Layout:weight ?  any better idea ?

```
<LinearLayout
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
  style="@style/ViewScreenTheme"
  android:orientation="vertical"
  android:background="@drawable/background"
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:layout_height="fill_parent">

<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:orientation="vertical"
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:layout_height="fill_parent">
  <RelativeLayout android:id="@+id/header" 
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:paddingTop="10dp"
    android:paddingBottom="10dp">

    <Button android:id="@+id/help_button" 
      android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
      style="@style/ButtonText"
      android:layout_margin="1dp"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:background="@drawable/help_button"
      android:paddingLeft="10px"
      android:paddingRight="10px"
      android:layout_marginRight="10px"/>
  </RelativeLayout>
  <RelativeLayout android:id="@+id/root" 
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:layout_below="@+id/header"
    android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="0dp"
    android:paddingTop="10dp"
    android:paddingBottom="10dp">
    <RelativeLayout
      android:orientation="vertical"
      android:layout_width="fill_parent"
      android:layout_height="384dp"
      android:background="#0fff"
      android:id="@+id/canvas_layout">
    </RelativeLayout>
  </RelativeLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

I want canvas_layout which is last relative layout to cover some part in every screen.

Comment: Provide code of your xml file pls

Comment: You have to post your layout XML file, else it is hard to help.

Comment: I added xml file guys please check it.

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion the best way to deal with screen sizes (if I understand correctly your question) is to use the resource qualifier to provide resources. You can find some guideline [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/providing-resources.html).

You, then, have to specify the varoius layout for the sizes you will need.